# Android convert base64 encoded string into image view

Tags: android, imageview, base64

I want to convert base64 encoded string into bitmap so i can put it in image view, but getting error like

D/skia(7490): --- decoder->decode returned false and bitmap returns null value

My code is:

```
byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(imageData);

image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length));
```

Comment: Where did you get your base64 string? Are you sure it is valid?

Comment: i am getting base64 string from webservice. How we can check it is valid or not?

Comment: Can you post the code that gets the Base64 string?

Comment: ImageData is a base64encoded string only. size of the string length is same only what in webservice and what i am getting to device, but i can't able to show in imageview.

Answer (score 52):

Firts you have to check that the string you want to decode is vaild and has the intended value to be decoded and to do so, you can do something like below:

```
filePath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/SaudiScore/temporary_holder.jpg";
Bitmap selectedImage =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
String strBase64=Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, 0);
```

then you can decode the string that you just encoded and get the image back by doing something like the following:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(strBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
image.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

Comment: Actually I am getting encode string, sending to webservice and back to device, that time i am getting this error.

Comment: I got the same error before, I was facing the same problem, All what you have to do is to check the size of string which actually was an image that encoded before you save it into the remote database is as same as the size of string that you retrieved, once you got it exactly the same you will get the image using the code above.

Comment: I am comparing that string length and size also same only, but i can't able to show in imageview.

Comment: what is the type of data you used to save the string on the database?

Comment: also how did you post the string to be save in remote database?

Comment: I am not saving to database, directly using as a string. For Sending also string only. I need to save in to database ?

Answer (score 28):

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(mBase64string, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,decodedString.length);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
String base = "Base64 string values of some image";

byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(base.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

ImageView image = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length));
```

Try this code.

Comment: when I use `setImageBitmap` my shows nothing. why is that so?

Comment: Check whether your base64 is correct first. if that is correct. then you may be trying to add the image after loading the view. Check your image view id as well.

Answer (score 0):

This method can help:

```
private void setExistImage(ImageView imageView, String base64String){
    if (!base64String.isEmpty()) {
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Decode/Convert base64 string to image

```
    imageBytes = Base64.decode(imageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0,imageBytes.length);
    image.setImageBitmap(decodedImage);
```

Comment: Please explain what the original asker was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
 byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(strBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
image.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

I was using the above solution .It always returned errors like decoded String is null,IllegalStateException ..
All I did was I just wrapped that in a try catch