# How to load Image with Picasso using base64?

Tags: android, base64, picasso

[Picasso documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFm5E.png)

As you can see using the link that, Picasso has only 3 options to load an image. My question is how to load an image if you have a base64 string parsed from JSON response from an api?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374840/download-base64-image-on-a-protected-site-using-picasso/42852617#42852617

Comment: Decode base64 string to normal string and load image

Comment: see this link--- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683032/android-convert-base64-encoded-string-into-image-view

Comment: I worked both with Glide and with Picasso. Glide makes it a lot easier to work with base64 strings and bitmaps. If it is possible you could switch to Glide?

Answer (score 3):

There are no additional methods to do this process in Picasso, you can use the native Java method to convert Base64 text to bytes array then simply get the job done.

You can get the Bitmap image so you can run Picasso using Bitmap as well.

The Base64 text should be formatted as: `data:image/png;base64,iV....`

```
String base64Image = base64Text.split(",")[1];
byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(base64Image.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length));
```