# Failing to draw URI format using Picasso library on android

Tags: android

I'm trying to draw this URI:

```
String image = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
```

with Picasso using this Syntanx:

```
Picasso.get().load(String.valueOf(image)).into(cameraActivity.imageView);
```

**EDIT1:**

I've used this approach: (from string convert it to Uri then to bitmap)

```
            String image = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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";

            Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(image);

            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);

            cameraActivity.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

but it says that I attempt to invoked getContentResolver() on a null object reference. and I'm calling it from activity that extends AppCompactActivity.

Comment: Picasso might not support that. The only sign of it that I see is [a rejected pull request from 2014](https://github.com/square/picasso/pull/404).

Comment: Is there any other library that might do that job?

Comment: I have not looked into this, sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android convert base64 encoded string into image view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683032/android-convert-base64-encoded-string-into-image-view)

Comment: you might try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15683305/7360848

Comment: @MartinZeitler i suggest better putting it on duplicate you can suggest him to try that method.

Comment: @Ashish Sorry, but I see no reason to do that, when it is a certain duplicate... this is neither an `Uri`, nor is Picasso required to accomplish the task.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, what do you mean by duplicate? can you explain to me what am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: From wikipedia I do see now that: "The data URI scheme can use Base64 to represent file contents. For instance, background images and fonts can be specified in a CSS stylesheet file as data: URIs, instead of being supplied in separate files." but how do I convert that?

Comment: @HarelYacovian please just see the Q&A which I've flagged as duplicate. based upon this you can simply create a method which sets that `base64` encoded `String` as source for an `ImageView`. It's some more effort, than it would be with a `WebView` `<img />` node, but it's generally simple, while not over-complicating it. In the web-context this may count as an URI scheme, but on Android this is not a valid `Uri` (probably the source of confusion). In Java one has to decode it, which the `WebKit` engine internally does.